# How to retrieve the current windows logged on user in ADF Model?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, oracle-adf

**How to retrieve the current windows logged on user in ADF Model**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model layer should be independent of your UI layer, so the right way to do this is to have a service method on your Application Module that accepts a parameter - than have your UI layer which knows the user who logged in call that method and pass the parameter to the model layer.

That said, if you are using ADF security, then you can access the currently logged in user using groovy expressions or EL expressions.
More on this in the security seminar here:
http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/11gdemos/adfinsidersecurity/adfinsidersecurity.html